# Pyspark : "ImportError: cannot import name 'st_makePoint'

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, geospatial

I am trying to enter some data in postgresql database using pyspark. There is one field in postresql table which defined as data type GEOGRAPHY(Point). I have written below pyspark code to creat this field using longitude and latitude

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import st_makePoint
df = (Load input file into pyspark dataframe)
df = df.withColumn("Location", st_makePoint(col("Longitude"), col("Latitude")))
Next step is load the data into postgresql
```

But I am getting the error

```
"ImportError: cannot import name 'st_makePoint'
```

I think st_makePoint is part of pyspark.sql.function. Not sure why it is giving error. Please help.
Also if there is better way of entering the Geography(Point) field in postgresql from pyspark please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [documentation](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/spark/pyspark.html) of **`geo-mesa`**

Registering user-defined types and functions can be done manually by invoking **`geomesa_pyspark.init_sql()`** on the Spark session object:

```
import geomesa_pyspark
geomesa_pyspark.init_sql(spark)
```

Then you can use [st_mkPoint](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/spark/sparksql_functions.html#st-makepoint)